# Using sketch.js I want to download more of the produced data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I press the download key on it does not download the quote that is present. Is there a way to change this? I tried playing around with the "data-" tag but can get nothing to work.

Here is the code

```
<title>SNUGGLETOOTH</title>

</head>

<body>

    <nav>

        <div id="SketchTools">
    <!-- Basic tools -->
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#000000" title="Black"><img src="img/black_icon.png" alt="Black"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ff0000" title="Red"><img src="img/red_icon.png" alt="Red"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#00ff00" title="Green"><img src="img/green_icon.png" alt="Green"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#0000ff" title="Blue"><img src="img/blue_icon.png" alt="Blue"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ffff00" title="Yellow"><img src="img/yellow_icon.png" alt="Yellow"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#00ffff" title="Cyan"><img src="img/cyan_icon.png" alt="Cyan"/></a>

    <!-- Advanced colors -->
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#e74c3c" title="Alizarin"><img src="img/alizarin_icon.png" alt="Alizarin"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#c0392b" title="Pomegrante"><img src="img/pomegrante_icon.png" alt="Pomegrante"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#2ecc71" title="Emerald"><img src="img/emerald_icon.png" alt="Emerald"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#1abc9c" title="Torquoise"><img src="img/torquoise_icon.png" alt="Torquoise"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#3498db" title="Peter River"><img src="img/peterriver_icon.png" alt="Peter River"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#9b59b6" title="Amethyst"><img src="img/amethyst_icon.png" alt="Amethyst"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#f1c40f" title="Sun Flower"><img src="img/sunflower_icon.png" alt="Sun Flower"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#f39c12" title="Orange"><img src="img/orange_icon.png" alt="Orange"/></a>

    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ecf0f1" title="Clouds"><img src="img/clouds_icon.png" alt="Clouds"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#bdc3c7" title="Silver"><img src="img/silver_icon.png" alt="Silver"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#7f8c8d" title="Asbestos"><img src="img/asbestos_icon.png" alt="Asbestos"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#34495e" title="Wet Asphalt"><img src="img/wetasphalt_icon.png" alt="Wet Asphalt"/></a>
   </br> <a href="#SketchPad" data-color="#ffffff" title="Eraser"><img src="img/eraser_icon.png" alt="Eraser"/></a>

    <!-- Size options -->
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="1"><img src="img/pencil_icon.png" alt="Pencil"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="3"><img src="img/pen_icon.png" alt="Pen"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="5"><img src="img/stick_icon.png" alt="Stick"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="9"><img src="img/smallbrush_icon.png" alt="Small brush"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="15"><img src="img/mediumbrush_icon.png" alt="Medium brush"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="50"><img src="img/bigbrush_icon.png" alt="Big brush"/></a>
    <a href="#SketchPad" data-size="90"><img src="img/bucket_icon.png" alt="Huge bucket"/></a>

    <a href="#SketchPad" data-download='png' id="DownloadPng">Download</a>
    <br/>
  </div>
        <div class="links">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="ficon.png" alt="Facebook"></li>
            <li><img src="igramicon.png" alt="Instagram"></li>
            <li><img src="picon.png" alt="Pinterest"></li>
            <li><img src="mcicon.png" alt="Mixcloud"></li>
            <li><img src="twicon.png" alt="Twitter"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="message">

        <div data id="quote"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        { text: "Snuggletooth likes pancakes"},
        { text: "Would you like Snuggletooth to tuck you in?"},
        { text: " Snuggletooth loves you"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth is here for you"},
        { text: "Did you know that Snuggletooth </br>can be in 2 places at once?"},
        { text: "Heyyyy!<br> I was just thinking about you </br>Love Snuggletooth" },
        { text: "Wanna Sandwich??</br>xSnuggletooth"},
        { text: "Want some breakfast???</br> ;) Snuggletooth"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth-a-riffic!!!"},    
        { text: "Snuggletooth makes great popcorn!"},
        { text: "Come over to Snuggletooth's! He makes a great guacamole!"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth likes his bubblebaths to smell like bubblegum"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth wants to know what are you up to later?"},
        { text: "Snuggletooth-a-licious!!!"},
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '' +  '';
    })();
  </script>

    </div>
    </nav>
    <canvas id="SketchPad" width="1125" height="600">

    </canvas>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#SketchPad').sketch();
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What is question ? , expected result ?

Comment: Right now when I click the download button everything copies except for what is in the "message" div, I can't figure out how to get it to copy as well as the drawing that one can make using sketch.js

Comment: Not tried sketch.js . Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Is requirement to set `canvas` with `.message` text ?

Comment: Sure, here is the Jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/e1ovm9mn/   When pressing the download button I wanted to be able to keep the text as well as the lines that one could draw on the canvas

Comment: Is expected result to export `canvas` with text of `.quote` ?

Comment: Yes that is what is expected

Comment: Try utilizing `window.URL.createObjectURL` , adding `style` element to exported objectURL; see post.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `window.URL.createObjectURL` , also adding `style` element to exported objectURL . See [Drawing DOM objects into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

```
$(function() {
    $('#SketchPad').sketch();
    $("#DownloadPng").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    var canvas = document.getElementById('SketchPad');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var style = $("style");

    var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1125" height="600">' 
       + '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' 
       + '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' 
       + $(".message")[0].outerHTML 
       + '</div>' 
       + '<style xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'   
       + style[0].innerHTML + '</style>'
       + '</foreignObject>' 
       + '</svg>';

    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    var popup = window.open(url, "popup")

    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e1ovm9mn/1/

Comment: Thanks for trying, it doesn't work though, nothing at all is exported anymore. But you did give me some other ideas to try and look for. At first I was thinking that perhaps I could use the <data> tag somewhere in the html. But I am now starting to look in the JS a bit more acutely

Comment: @reivax7 _"nothing at all is exported anymore"_ `popup` not opened at new `window` at http://jsfiddle.net/e1ovm9mn/1/ , there ? Appear to open new tab with `objectURL` `svg` , here. Could alternatively convert `url` to `data URI` instead of objectURL